# How to remove a 1:1 association in sails.js?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Currently I'm setting the association attribute to `null` but this throws exceptions in some instances?

Eg.

`Profile.update({user: user.id}, {user: null}, function (err, profiles) {});`

Is there a *proper* way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proper way.  There is a bug in the PubSub implementation for 1:1 associations that [has now been patched](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/pull/1445/files), so going forward you shouldn't see any exceptions.

Comment: why is there no add or delete method akin to many to many associations?

Comment: It's a semantic thing.  With to-many associations, you're "adding" or "removing" from a collection.  With one-to-one, we're just setting the relationship (we may add a 'set' method at some point).